# parsed_json = kstream.map(lambda (k,v): json.loads()), invalid syntax error problem

Tags: python, machine-learning, lambda, data-science, recommendation-engine

Getting below error:

> SyntaxError: invalid syntax error on this line of the code ->
>   parsed_json = kstream.map(lambda (k,v): json.loads()) arrow indicating
>   (>k,a), link to the code is 
>   https://github.com/patilankita79/Location-based-Restaurants-Recommendation-System/blob/master/BigDataProject/Consumer.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is in lambda function signature. The correct is:

```
kstream.map(lambda k, v: json.loads(v))
```